# what should be the command line for creating executable using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a Project in which a main.py file which has below line for passing the command line argument

```
os.system(r'robot -d %s\\results -v CWD:%s -A %s\\arguments.txt  data\util\data' % (cwd, cwd, cwd))
```

The command line which I am giving to create the executable is

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "arguments.txt;." main.py
```

the executable is created but giving error -

```
[ ERROR ] Parsing 'data\util\data' failed: File or directory to execute does not exist.
```

below is the directory structure.

main project -

> arguments.txt
> main.py
> datacreation/util/data

main.spec is as follow

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['(path_to)\\Desktop\\(path_to)\\main_project'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('arguments.txt', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='main')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add your file `arguments.txt` in one file mode, the data will extract in a temp path like `C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEIXXX`, so in your command line, it needs to load from this path which would be equal to [`sys._MEIPASS`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/runtime-information.html#using-file-and-sys-meipass).

```
import os
import sys


def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)


arguments_path = resource_path("arguments.txt")
data_path = resource_path("path_to_ur_data")
...

os.system(r'robot -d %s\\results -v CWD:%s -A %s  data\util\data' % (cwd, cwd, arguments_path)) # add all external path here
```

Comment: path_to_ur_data will consist oh which file arguments or data/util/data?

Comment: It can be a directory or file but when it is a directory you need to bundle it with [`Tree`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced-topics.html#the-toc-and-tree-classes)